# Vanced Youtube & Native Youtube App crashes after ArrowOS update on a6020a46

Tags: root-access, youtube, crashes, systemless-root

I have a rooted Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus running TWRP+Magisk+OpenGApps+ArrowOS(android v10).No MicroG.
I installed Vanced Manager and Youtube Vanced in it(sometime after the February update) and it was working perfectly. I had given Vanced Manager superuser permission.

Recently there was an update with 5 March 2021 security patch which I applied yesterday, since then Vanced seems to have completely broken while everthing else runs fine.

Things I have tried -

1. Uninstalling Youtube Vanced from Vanced Manager, uninstalling Vanced Manager then re-downloading Vanced Manager from their GitHub releases page and reinstalling Youtube Vanced with SuperUser permission granted to Vanced Manager.
2. Re-Installing ArrowOs update from TWRP install and then wiping Cache/Dalvik. Trying same thing again but without wipping Cache/Dalvik.
3. Booting to TWRP and selecting Wipe > Advanced Wipe > selecting only Cache

I open the App, click on a video and Youtube crashes.
Here is the log -

```
time: 1615626523312
msg: Native crash: Segmentation fault
stacktrace: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/A6020a46/A6020a46:5.1.1/LMY47V/A6020a46_S105_161124_ROW:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-03-13 14:38:41+0530
pid: 9210, tid: 9233, name: yt-critical3-1  >>> com.google.android.youtube <<<
uid: 10181
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000077a4f6bcd8  x2  0000000000000038  x3  0000000000000004
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  000000780fb67c37  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000036
    x8  00000077a4f6bcd8  x9  81d816781534a741  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000003
    x12 000000773bb0e000  x13 0000000000000040  x14 fffffffffc000000  x15 0086401000000008
    x16 00000078940a5890  x17 0000007894098130  x18 00000077a1a98000  x19 000000773bb0e0c0
    x20 000000773bb0e0c0  x21 000000773bb0e0e8  x22 000000773bb0e0e0  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 0000000077450758  x25 0000000077450218  x26 0000000077450748  x27 000000007708ffe0
    x28 000000773bb0e0c8  x29 00000077a4f6bcc0
    sp  00000077a4f6bbf0  lr  00000077f9c030ec  pc  00000077f9c031f8

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000401f8  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (JavaMediaCodecListWrapper::JavaMediaCodecListWrapper(android::sp<android::IMediaCodecList>)+128) (BuildId: 5048733c629f4c47102dc6d3e92b512f)
      #01 pc 00000000000400e8  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (getCodecList(_JNIEnv*)+152) (BuildId: 5048733c629f4c47102dc6d3e92b512f)
      #02 pc 000000000003f4ec  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaCodecList_getCodecCount(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+8) (BuildId: 5048733c629f4c47102dc6d3e92b512f)
      #03 pc 00000000002818c0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (BuildId: ba17fdaa4953a5a20b9a87065f5c2176fd5803b1)
```

I got it when a notif like "Youtube keeps stopping" showed up and there was an option called 'Copy crash log URL'(del.dog/futhypock). Going to the URL on my phone showed this output.However typing it in my pc yielded nothing.

The strangest thing is that uninstalling youtube vanced and then installing the official youtube app from the play store yields the exact same behaviour.

Here is the log (del.dog/anothyfutt)-

```
time: 1615627396186
msg: Native crash: Segmentation fault
stacktrace: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/A6020a46/A6020a46:5.1.1/LMY47V/A6020a46_S105_161124_ROW:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-03-13 14:53:15+0530
pid: 11931, tid: 11964, name: yt-critical2-5  >>> com.google.android.youtube <<<
uid: 10182
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000779f0a2438  x2  0000000000000038  x3  0000000000000004
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  000000780fb67c37  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000036
    x8  000000779f0a2438  x9  81d816781534a741  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000032
    x12 0000007738a00000  x13 0000000000000040  x14 fffffffffc000000  x15 a04c000000000000
    x16 00000078940a5890  x17 0000007894098130  x18 000000779e26c000  x19 0000007738a00c80
    x20 0000007738a00c80  x21 0000007738a00ca8  x22 0000007738a00ca0  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 0000000000000008  x25 000000779f0a6020  x26 00000077fdd1c0b0  x27 0000000000000002
    x28 0000007738a00c88  x29 000000779f0a2420
    sp  000000779f0a2350  lr  00000077f9c030ec  pc  00000077f9c031f8

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000401f8  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (JavaMediaCodecListWrapper::JavaMediaCodecListWrapper(android::sp<android::IMediaCodecList>)+128) (BuildId: 5048733c629f4c47102dc6d3e92b512f)
      #01 pc 00000000000400e8  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (getCodecList(_JNIEnv*)+152) (BuildId: 5048733c629f4c47102dc6d3e92b512f)
      #02 pc 000000000003f4ec  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaCodecList_getCodecCount(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+8) (BuildId: 5048733c629f4c47102dc6d3e92b512f)
      #03 pc 00000000002818c0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (BuildId: ba17fdaa4953a5a20b9a87065f5c2176fd5803b1)
```

I couldn't make head or tail of what this log means. I tried searching for "msg: Native crash: Segmentation fault" and found [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/631) but I couldn't understand that either and the links they provided are Greek and Latin to me. I also found [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash) but again understood nothing.

How do I get Youtube Vanced to work again? Please help a newbie here who really loves Youtube Vanced. I will be happy to provide any further logs should you require them, but I don't know how to collect logs and would appreciate it greatly if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Based on your description something is wrong with the customROM you have installed. Those crash reports can only be sent to the ROM developer(s), may be they are helpful to them. Regular users typically don't understand a word of such a report.

Comment: @Robert could you point me in the right direction? An email id of the maintainer of a6020a46 perhaps where I can describe my issue? Or should I just open an issue on the GitHub page of ArrowOS?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with that custom ROM. But "a6020a46" sounds more like a git commit hash (thus it is simply a version identifier) than a developer.

Comment: a6020a46 is the model/code name of my phone Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus

Comment: Should I just forget resolving this issue and format everything and reinstall my OS? I'm also having strange problems with accessing stuff in my storage. eg: downloaded files are getting corrupted and I am unable to delete files in my Downloads directory with my file manager(the default aosp one). Perhaps there are some permission issues?

Comment: I get this error when trying to install the ROM, it's the only error I get. "failed to mount /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system at /system: Device or resource busy." The way I've done it is just select Install from TWRP and point to the ZIP of the custom ROM. Is this incorrect in any way? Could you tell me how I can do update my system correctly?